# Service missing displayed when it axiously exists

Tags: symfony

I can't figure out why this error regarding my 'missing' service occurs:

```
The service "user.send_email" has a dependency on a non-existent service "test".


test:
    class: ..
    arguments: ...

user.send_email:
    class: ...
    arguments: [@test]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

EDIT: the services are in different bundles.

Comment: Try to put in the same bundle. Perhaps the services of the other bundle are not loaded. PS: What do you mean by axiously? Obviously?

Comment: Depending on symfony version have try to declare arguments like this arguments: ['@test'] ?